# Javascript to read dynamic amount of dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, select, dynamic, multiple-instances

I have a dynamic amount of select boxes (depending on the first one, the number of the following ones varies) that were dynamically created by ajax/php with only the first one populated such as:

```
<select class="selector">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
<select class="selector">
</select>
<select class="selector">
</select>
...
<select class="selector">
</select>
<select class="selector">
</select>
```

I need to have a javascript that detects a change on any of them and populates the following one and cleans the rest of them.
I've been using this approach to populate a fixed number:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"find_content.php",
        data:{current_select_id:$current_select_id},
        success:function(data)
        {
                $(data).appendTo($following_select);
        }
    });
```

I think this problem needs some sort of recursive function...
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the desired output more clearly

Comment: Basically whenever I want to create a new entity in the database I'll be presented with different types. Each type may have a different amount of categories and sub-categories to classify it.

Comment: As an example if you select type of entry to be 'cars', then categories to classify the car will be brand->model->engine_size. I you choose 'planes' the categories will be brand->model->engine_type->number_of_passengers.

Comment: Of course that all the categories' contents will be in the database and hence the reason to have one select box populated after the previous one. This will be done by an external php script already done. My problem is the main window with a variable number or select boxes and how to handle them.